# What is the best way to design the data tables for objects that derive from the same base class

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to remodel a database with the following basic structure - I have People each of which can host various Events which will be classified as on of several EventTypes every Season.
I could easily create the database tables along this scenario and have an relationship between Events and EventTypes. The problem is every different type of event has a different set of properties and I am trying to avoid creating the Events table with so many fields, many of which will be null or blank depending on the EventType chosen.
Question: How best can I design the data layer such that I can have a base class called Events and objects of the various EventTypes inherit from this base class.
(I hope this isn't confusing, please ask and I will clarify, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you put the common ones in the Events table.  For specialized cases, create additional tables that match with appropriate fields.

Although it is possible to use other solutions such as Polymorphic associations, etc. in most cases it's much simpler for most folks to add more tables and columns and call them what they are.  One example where this helps, despite this increased in the number of tables, is field validations.

If all the columns were the same then yeah, event_type, but if so many column are different then no.

Trying to make everything really generic or numbered columns (yuch) aren't good options.  Relational Databases work best (for legibility and maintainablity) when you name tables and columns like this.

There are also non-SQL options that are 'schema-less' and support this kind of variety.  They are noSQL implementations like mongoDB, Hadoop, CouchDB, etc.

Comment: yes it'll scale.  To scale well with really large amounts of data, you'd probably consider using a noSQL option if you data structures are that 'fluid'.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to create an event table with the base properties and an EventType column, and a different table for each of the different event types.  The EventType column in the "base" table would tell you which table you would need to join to in order to get the rest of the properties for the event.  In your DAL you could then use a factory pattern to get the correct Event subclass by using the EventType property on a base event class.